# Getting "Empty suite" error when running the automation script for pytest

Tags: python, android, automation, pycharm, pytest

I am trying to run the pytest automation script. While running the below code I am getting "Empty suite" error in the pycharm.

```
def setup():
    des_caps = {
        "platformName": "Android",
        "platformVersion": "10",
        "deviceName": "emulator-5554",
        "app": "D:\\example.apk",
        "appActivity": "com.example.SplashActivity",
        "appPackage": "com.example"
    }

    driver = webdriver.Remote("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub", des_caps)
```

I tried modifying the above code as provided below

```
def setup():
    des_caps = {
        "platformName": "Android",
        "platformVersion": "10",
        "deviceName": "emulator-5554",
        "app": "D:\\example.apk",
        "appActivity": "com.example.SplashActivity",
        "appPackage": "com.example"
    }

driver = webdriver.Remote("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub", des_caps)
```

But getting "Unresolved reference 'des_caps'" error.

Comment: `des_caps` is defined inside the method but `driver` is using it outside the method so it is not accessible, did you mean to create the `driver` object within the method? if so, then there is an indentation issue.

Comment: No, I don't want to create driver object inside method. it should be outside. Can you help me on this

Comment: then you need to return the `des_caps` object so that it can be used outside of the method but creating a method for just returning a object sounds meaningless here unless you have something else in the method or you can create the `des_caps` object outside the method in the same scope as `driver`